# List copied files in bash

Tags: bash

I need to copy files from one directory to another (pretty obvious :) ) but I want to store list of files that were copied with destination path. So let's say I have:
/mnt/a/f1
/mnt/a/f2

and I want to copy all files from 'a' to root so I do:
`cp -rv /mnt/a/* /`

output from cp I will have will look like:

`` `/mnt/a/f1` -> `/f1` ``

`/mnt/a/f2` -> `/f2`

and now I want to store in some file list that will looks like:

`/f1`

/f2

Does somebody know how can I achieve such output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cp -rv /mnt/a/* / 2>&1 | cut -d\` -f4 | tee thefile.txt
```

Something like this (untested).

Comment: Great! Thanks! Works almost fine, I put wrong output format (for cp) so here is slightly corrected solution: cp -rv mnt/a/ / 2>&1 | cut -d\` -f3 | cut -d\' -f1 | tee thefile.txt

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, my `cut` was based on your output, but glad you figured it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use something like

```
cp -rv files dest > output_file
```

and redirect all the output to a file, but if you *absolutely* need to split it so you only have the ending I would recommend writing something quickly in Ruby, Python, or Perl and just symlink it as something like "verbose_cp". If you really want to you can do the splitting in [Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/split-string-based-on-delimiter-in-bash), though in my opinion doing it in languages with stronger string handling would be much easier.